# Webpack Node.js API and ES6

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, ecmascript-6

I've created node API webpack compiler in ES6. Without es6 everything works well. But if I use es6, I get this:

```
[13:29:41] TypeError: Cannot read property 'concat' of undefined
at new NormalModuleFactory (/private/var/www/MyProject/legacy/shop/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:115:51)
at Compiler.createNormalModuleFactory (/private/var/www/MyProject/legacy/shop/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:586:31)
at Compiler.newCompilationParams (/private/var/www/MyProject/legacy/shop/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:603:30)
at Compiler.compile (/private/var/www/MyProject/legacy/shop/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:611:23)
at readRecords.err (/private/var/www/MyProject/legacy/shop/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:284:11)
at Compiler.readRecords (/private/var/www/MyProject/legacy/shop/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:479:11)
at hooks.run.callAsync.err (/private/var/www/MyProject/legacy/shop/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:281:10)
at AsyncSeriesHook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (/private/var/www/MyProject/legacy/shop/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:32:10), <anonymous>:6:1)
at AsyncSeriesHook.lazyCompileHook (/private/var/www/MyProject/legacy/shop/node_modules/tapable/lib/Hook.js:154:20)
at hooks.beforeRun.callAsync.err (/private/var/www/MyProject/legacy/shop/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:278:19)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

**This is my code:**

```
import {Compiler} from 'webpack';
const config = require("./config/webpack.config");

class WebpackCompiler {
    constructor(context) {
        this.config = config;
        this.compilerOptions = {};
        this.compiler = new Compiler(context);
    }

    start() {
        this.compiler.options = Object.assign({}, this.config, this.compilerOptions);
        this.compiler.run().then((stats) => this._handleStats(stats)).catch((err) => this._handleErrors(err));
    }

    setOutput(output) {
        this.compilerOptions.output = output;
    }

    setEntries(entires) {
        this.compilerOptions.entry = entires;
    }

    _handleStats(stats) {
        const statsErrors = stats.toJson();

        if (stats.hasErrors()) {
            console.error(statsErrors.errors.toString({
                chunks: false,
                colors: true
            }));
        }

        if (stats.hasWarnings()) {
            console.warn(statsErrors.warnings.toString({
                chunks: false,
                colors: true
            }));
        }
    }

    _handleErrors(err) {
        if (err) {
            console.error(err.stack || err);
            if (err.details) {
                console.error(err.details);
            }
            return;
        }
    }
}

export const CompilerFactory = {
    create: function (context) {
        return new WebpackCompiler(context);
    }
}
```

**After this, something like this:**

```
 var compiler = CompilerFactory.create(WEBPACK_CONTEXT);
    compiler.setEntries({bundle: "./js/main.js"});
    compiler.setOutput("./js/compiled");
    compiler.start();
```

**And simple webpack config:**

```
const path = require('path');
const sourcePath = path.resolve("MY_PATH_TO_ROOT");

const mode = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' || "development";

module.exports = {
    mode: mode,
    node: {
        __dirname: true
    },
    watchOptions: {
        poll: true
    },
    devtool: "eval",
    entry: {},
    output: {
        filename: '[name].js'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(js)$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'babel-loader',
                        options: {
                            sourceMaps: true
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },

    externals: {
        "jquery": "jQuery"
    },

    resolve: {
        modules: [
            path.resolve(sourcePath, 'node_modules')
        ]
    }
};
```

Problem is after calling method `Run()`. In NormalModuleFactory.js, problem is in this row:

```
this.ruleSet = new RuleSet(options.defaultRules.concat(options.rules));
```

As I say, there is no much informations in the webpack documentation about using ES6. Do you everyone know, where is problem? 
Thank you for your time.

Comment: can you show the `NormalModuleFactory` file, your error has nothing to deal with ES6, it's just because the `defaultRules` attribute is undefined

Comment: Sure, I know. But this file is not mine, but webpack's js factory.: https://github.com/webpack/webpack/blob/master/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js/